# How can 3-state bit packed together?

Tags: encoding, compression, bit, bit-fields, integer-arithmetic

I am looking for a clever solution that would allow to pack into a 16 bits integer, at least nine 3-state 'bits'. It should also still be possible to easily set the value of one these 3-state 'bit'.

As an example, it could be used to encode a tic-tac-toe position, the tree state being, _ (empty), X (me), O (opponent) for the nine square of the board.

Naturally using 2 bits per square would do the job, but it would require 18bits overall. Is there an encoding that would use only 1.7 bits at most per square, and still stay simple for working with it ?

Comment: Only if you remove the "and still stay simple for working with it" requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can store ten 3-state values in a 16-bit integer, since 3<sup>10</sup> = 59049 < 65536. Simply encode a 10-digit base-3 number into a 16-bit integer, and pull the digits out going the other way.

To encode each digit `d`, the repeated operation is `n = 3*n + d`. To decode the digits in the opposite order, the repeated operations are `d = n % 3` and `n /= 3`.

Comment: Division and modulo are not all that efficient, but I'm sure this isn't strictly needed if one uses some [bit twiddling hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Comment: @ThomasMueller Modern compilers already know those, so you don't need to bother. I just tried clang and looked at the assembler output, and it knew to implement the multiply with a load effective address, and to do the modulo and divide with a multiply and shift. It even figured out that it only needed to do one multiply to get both the divide and the modulo results on the same input.